# Best place for UTF-8

Tags: html, .htaccess, optimization

A simple question.  Where is the best place to have the UTF-8 declared.  I have it once in my .htaccess and again in my .html documents.  Is this redundant?  Is the .htaccess good enough?

Answer (score 0):

I thinks in .html documents is the best place. File .htaccess in most cases it uses to redirection

Answer (score 0):

There's no "correct" answer, only per-need practice or common practices...

If you're using a framework then the main declaration page (config.php for example) should be the default best practice *in my opinion *

In that way if you're running a couple of projects on the same host, you can manage encoding separately, when usually the same framework uses the same encoding

Answer (score 0):

The best place is in the html documents imo, because it's common practice in the programming world to do so (as far as I know).